# Why does this racket function need an argument? And how does it work?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lisp, racket

I am a beginner in Racket and the following code is from University of Washington's Racket Programming course-

```
(define s "hello")
(define (pow1 x y)
  (if(= y 0)
     1
     (* x (pow1( - y 1)))))

(define pow2
  (lambda(x)
    (lambda(y)
      (pow1 x y))))
(define three (pow2 3))
```

From what I have read, for arguments to be passed in Racket the format should be -

```
(define (id id id) expression)
```

Why does it not hold true for three? And how exactly does three work?

**EDIT1-** When I run `(pow1 1 2)` I get an error saying that number of arguments given is 1, and when  I write `(pow1 2 3 4)` it says number of arguments is 3. What is going on?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `(define s "hello")` simply defines a variable `s` (as `"hello"`). It's not a function. Similarly, `three` would be bound to the result of `(pow2 3)`.

Comment: My bad. I wasn't asking about s. I just want to know how three would execute. (three 2) returns 9 but why so?  Where does that 2 go?

Comment: Note that `(define (id id id) expression)` is just an abbreviation for `(define id (lambda (id id) expression))`.

Comment: One thing that is worth knowing is that `(define (x ...) ...)` is a syntactic shorthand for `(define x (lambda (...) ...)` in Racket (and in Scheme more generally).  So `pow2` could be defined as `(define (pow2 x) (lambda (y) (pow1 x y)))` which is possibly clearer: `pow2` is a function which returns a function.

Comment: Guys please check the edit.

Comment: `(pow1( - y 1))` calls `pow1` with 1 argument. But this is a separate problem and has nothing to do with your original question.

Answer (score 3):

```
(define pow2
  (lambda(x)
    (lambda(y)
      (pow1 x y))))
```

This defines `pow2` as a `lambda` expression of some kind.

```
(define three (pow2 3))
```

This defines `three` as the result of `(pow2 3)`. What is `(pow2 3)`? Well, let's inline the value of `pow2`:

```
(pow2 3)
; inline pow2
((lambda(x)
   (lambda(y)
     (pow1 x y)))
  3)
```

Applying a lambda (of a parameter `x`) to a value (such as `3`) substitutes the value in the body of the lambda (i.e. we can replace `x` by `3`):

```
(lambda(y)
  (pow1 3 y))
```

Now this is the value of `three`.

Doing `(three 2)` proceeds like this:

```
(three 2)
; inline three
((lambda(y)
   (pow1 3 y))
  2)
; apply lambda
(pow1 3 2)
```

... and from there on it's just a call to `pow1`.